# How to convert cid links to http links?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i'm writing an app that parse emails from a pop3 mailbox.
I've extracted the attached files of the messages and now i want to convert the link in the message text.

That means 
I've this : `src="cid:image001.png@01CC9ED6.84327130"`
and i want something like : `src="http://xxx/image001.png"`

could you help me whith regexp please ?
`preg_replace('/cid:/', 'http://xxx')` and now how to remove the sequence after the '@' ?

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with:

```
$input  = 'src="cid:image001.png@01CC9ED6.84327130"';
$output = preg_replace('/cid:(.*?)@[\w.]*/', 'http://xxx/$1', $input);

// string(29) "src="http://xxx/image001.png""
```